# Do I need to 'Create New App' to create a new Facebook page tab?

Tags: facebook

I have an existing business page [located here](https://www.facebook.com/pages/Wines-For-Home/153306744766496) and on this page I want to create a series of 'tabs' (e.g. about us, recommended wines, etc.).

Firstly, to get this straight, am I doing 'create new app' for each new tab?  I don't want the user to have to grant any permission because the tabs are not really apps just information, though I can't figure out any other way to do it.

So, presuming I must 'create new app' before adding a new tab to my page, how do I then link the created app to my business page and show it as a tab? I have read many articles and searched here but there is no clear answer that I have found.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> Firstly, to get this straight, am I doing 'create new app' for each new tab?

Yes. You can only provide one page tab URL for each app, so you have to set up as many apps as you want different tabs.

> I don't want the user to have to grant any permission

As long as your apps don’t ask for any permissions, the user is not prompted to accept anything.

> how do I then link the created app to my business page and show it as a tab?

Use the [Facebook Page Tab Generator](https://apps.facebook.com/pagetabgenerator/) for that.

Comment: Thank you CBroe,

So, there is no alternative to creating a new 'tab' other than to create an 'app' for it? That is what I was trying to ask.

With regards to the Page Tab Generator, I am not German but managed to figure out I just enter my app's URL into the box and generate a link.  It generated http://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=https://apps.facebook.com/wines-of-the-month/&next=http://www.facebook.com but when I follow that it says 'an error occurred'.